# how to enable particular date of each month and disable other dates of every month in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, adminlte

I have two datepicker fields in my application which choose start date and end date. Also have one dropdown to choose format like Day,Week,Month.Means when user choose dropdown as day then all fields of end date and start date are enabled.when user select week as selected value then particular day of every week is enabled in end date datepicker based on day selected in start date.But now I want functionality such that when user select month in drop down and select one date in start date field then at that moment end date datepicker should get updated and it enable only that particular date in every month of calendar.I tried this code but it is not working for me.

```
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekDisabled', disableDate); 

    function getDateToDisable(selectedDate) {
    var dateToDisable= [];
    var date = new Date(selectedDate.date.valueOf());
    var selectedDate = date.getDate();
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if (i != selectedDate) {
            dateToDisable.push(i);
        }
    }
    return dateToDisable;
}
```

Please suggest best way to get this kind of functionality?